# SpellCheckerSession.isSessionDisconnected() always return true

Tags: android

I am trying to validate that the user checks the spelling correction suggestions but when I check if the session with the isSessionDisconnected method always returns true and therefore the getSentenceSuggestions or getSuggestions methods do not work either.

```
    final TextServicesManager tsm = (TextServicesManager) getSystemService(
            Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE);
    mScs = tsm.newSpellCheckerSession(null, Locale.ENGLISH, this, false);
    SpellCheckerInfo infoChecker = mScs.getSpellChecker();
    if(mScs.isSessionDisconnected()){
        Log.d(TAG, "is disconnected");
    }

    if (mScs != null) {
            // Instantiate TextInfo for each query
            // TextInfo can be passed a sequence number and a cookie number to identify the result
            if (isSentenceSpellCheckSupported()) {
                // Note that getSentenceSuggestions works on JB or later.
                Log.d(TAG, "Sentence spellchecking supported.");
                mScs.getSentenceSuggestions(new TextInfo[]{new TextInfo("ber")}, 3);
                mScs.getSentenceSuggestions(new TextInfo[]{new TextInfo("casade")}, 3);
                mScs.getSentenceSuggestions(new TextInfo[]{new TextInfo("hell othere")}, 3);
            } else {
                // Note that getSuggestions() is a deprecated API.
                // It is recommended for an application running on Jelly Bean or later
                // to call getSentenceSuggestions() only.
                mScs.getSuggestions(new TextInfo("ber"), 3);
                mScs.getSuggestions(new TextInfo("hllo"), 3);
                mScs.getSuggestions(new TextInfo("helloworld"), 3);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't obtain the spell checker service.");
        }
    }
```